# How to prevent CloudFormation stack resource being silently modified by another stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We have a CFN stack with a S3 BucketPolicy resource, however some other stacks within the same account also have S3 BucketPolicy defined for the same S3 bucket. How to prevent stack resource being modified silently by other CFN stacks?

Comment: Why would you have someone like that? It's bad design.

Comment: That's due to the account is being shared by the org. It is a bad design, but also need a solution for now until this bad pattern can be fixed.